# Over without absolute and without background

Tags: css, z-index

Is it possible to put one div over the other without background and without absolute position? This is a responsive design simplified. The content will change the width is %. So in this case I think I cannot use absolute positioning? Is there a way to put the divs trans over the others?

Here I use relative positioning but z-index does not seem to work. I do not understand why?

Here is the example to play: http://jsfiddle.net/WMXMW/1/

CSS:

```
#content{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:40%;
    overflow:hidden; /* a way of clearing float */
    text-align:center;
}

#text{
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:justify;
}

#menuTrans{
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    z-index:1;
    display:inline-block;
}
#blueTrans{
    float:left;
    width:50px; height:50px;
    opacity:0.5;
    z-index:0;
    background:blue;
}
#redTrans{
    float:left;
    width:50px; height:50px;
    opacity:0.5;
    z-index:0;
    background:red;
}



#menu{
    margin:0 auto;
    z-index:0;
    display:inline-block;
}
#blue{
    float:left;
    width:50px; height:50px;
    z-index:0;
    background:blue;
}
#red{
    float:left;
    width:50px; height:50px;
    z-index:0;
    background:red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="text"> 
        some text some text some text  
        some text some text some text
        some text some text some text 
        some text some text some text 
        some text some text some text 
        some text some text some text 
        some text some text some text 
        some text some text some text 
        some text some text some text 
    </div>   
    <div id="menu"> 
        <div id="red"> </div>
        <div id="blue"> </div>
    </div>

    <div id="menuTrans"> 
        <div id="redTrans"> </div>
        <div id="blueTrans"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use -ve margins

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/eugip9/sS2WX/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the element where you want to have it. If you're using relative position, you can do this by setting a left negative value:

```
#menuTrans{
  position:relative;
  left: -100px;
[...]
```

And to control which one is on the top, you need to give `#menu` also a relative position —or really any other than *static*— and so z-index will work.

Comment: Ok, with this they are in the same position. But then, how do you control witch one is on top?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the width of the elements, you can give them a negative margin. The elements that come later in the DOM will be on top.

```
#blueTrans{
    float:left;
    width:50px; height:50px;
    opacity:0.5;
    background:blue;
    margin-left: -50px;
}
#redTrans{
    float:left;
    width:50px; height:50px;
    opacity:0.5;
    background:red;
    margin-left: -50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WMXMW/2/

Comment: In your example the red is on top, not below